# Tensor Reshape Query

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have a image tensor of shape :-

```
N,C,H,W = 5,512,13,13
```

I need to take a mean across H and W dimensions so that the output is of shape :-

```
N,C,1,1
```

I am trying doing for loop but is there some better way to do so using reshape. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 import torch

 tz = torch.rand(5, 512, 13, 13)
 tzm = tz.mean(dim=(2,3), keepdim=True)
 tzm.shape
```

Output

```
torch.Size([5, 512, 1, 1])
```

Comment: Thanks Evgeny. I tried this solution, and it is working perfectly fine. Thanks a lot.